# Fibonacci Recursive returns endless number

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

My code results with endless number "2", I don't understand why.

Also my tutor told me to add validation for negative values - I don't know how to do it.

```
    public class FibonacciRecursive {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int fibonacciNumberOrder = 10;
        do {
            System.out.print(fibonacci(fibonacciNumberOrder) + " ");

        } while (true);
    }

    public static long fibonacci(int fibonacciNumberInOrder) {
        if (fibonacciNumberInOrder == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (fibonacciNumberInOrder <= 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        long fibonacci = fibonacci(-1) + fibonacci(-2);
        return fibonacci;
    }
}
```

edit:
When I changed that line

```
long fibonacci = fibonacci(-1) + fibonacci(-2);
```

to:

```
long fibonacci = fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder-1) + fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder-2);
```

It prints endless "55"

How should I change my code to make it work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the expected output?

Comment: I want it to print "1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55" when I ask for 10, or if I ask for 5, then I want it: "1, 1, 2, 3, 5". I want a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursing with constants! Change this

```
long fibonacci = fibonacci(-1) + fibonacci(-2);
```

to

```
long fibonacci = fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder-1) + fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder-2);
```

And, in your `while` loop in `main` - you need to modify `fibonacciNumberInOrder`

```
int fibonacciNumberOrder = 1;
do {
    System.out.print(fibonacci(fibonacciNumberOrder) + " ");
    fibonacciNumberOrder++;
} while (true);
```

Comment: Now it results with endless "55"

Comment: @user944047 What did you expect for `System.out.print(fibonacci(fibonacciNumberOrder) + " ");` where you always pass in ten?

Comment: I wanted to add validation for negative values, but I guess this is not a way to do it? I'm new to coding.

Comment: So, what should I do to add that validation for negative values and see ten fibonacci numbers, not every tenth?

Comment: You already have validation for negative values: `if (fibonacciNumberInOrder <= 2) {` - what are you asking?

Comment: Ok, so what should I do there to print this: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55. Instead of every tenth fibonacci number?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you calculate the Fibonacci number with constants instead of relative numbers to passed ones through, which is the point of recursion.

```
public static long fibonacci(int fibonacciNumberInOrder) {
    if (fibonacciNumberInOrder == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (fibonacciNumberInOrder <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    long fibonacci = fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder - 1) + fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder - 2);
    return fibonacci;
}
```

The key changed line is:

```
long fibonacci = fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder-1) + fibonacci(fibonacciNumberInOrder-2);
```